# Is it necessary to host the Adapter Service of BizTalk Services on runtime?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, biztalk-services

I have a question about the BizTalk Adapter Service for BizTalk Services. I know that the adapter runs in IIS - I would like to know if that is only necessary for development or for run-time too?

Because I would like to use BizTalk Services to insert XML messages into an Azure SQL:
[Using Azure BizTalk Services to Insert XML Messages into an Azure SQL Server](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22919.using-windows-azure-biztalk-services-to-insert-xml-messages-into-an-azure-sql-server.aspx)

Would I need to provide a server just for hosting the adapter? If so, that wouldn't make much sense to me

Answer (score 1):

roxor, I believe that you are correct in the suspicion that you need to host the adapter service and I agree that it makes no sense. I simply do not think this is a scenario currently 'properly' covered by BizTalk Services.

> The adapter service has been introduced to support integration with
>   several on-premises systems, SQL Server amongst them -
>
> The BizTalk Adapter Service feature allows an application in the cloud
>   to communicate with a Line-of-Business (LOB) system on-premise, in
>   your network, behind your firewall. Using the LOB adapters in the
>   BizTalk Adapter Pack (BAP), a BizTalk Adapter Service application can
>   execute LOB operations to the following on-premise LOB systems: •
>   Microsoft SQL Server
>
> • Oracle Database
>
> • Oracle E-Business Suite
>
> • SAP
>
> • Siebel eBusiness Applications

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh689889.aspx)

It does that by utilising Windows Azure Service Bus' Relay service. I don't think that Windows Azure SQL Database natively fits the model and although I can see how it can be done it does seem very awkward and quite pointless. In my humble opinion this article shouldn't have been published.

I would imagine that integration with SQL Database would be added to WABS natively eventually, until then, if it was down to me, I'd front it with a web service. Makes sense architecturally anyway.

Comment: hm I've tested the scenario right now and it seems to work although after stopping BizTalk Adapter Service site in IIS

Comment: I can't see how - it is the adapter service, hosted in IIS, that knows how to talk to SQL? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh689773.aspx

Comment: I wish this question could be answered, I can't... but it really seems to work after stopping IIS

Answer (score 0):

yes Adapter service is required during runtime .

the role of Adapter service is to pick the message from service bus relay and send it to Azure SQL DB .

i am checking how it works if Adapter service is in stop state .

you can refer the article for more knowledge of BiztalK adapter Service 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh689786.aspx

Regards
Mohit Gupta